# Pip Install EOFError

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I am using windows 10 and recently updated to python 3.8. I'm trying to install pygame on the new version and tried `py -m pip install -U pygame --user` but got this error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_e3mjg4_\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I haven't been able to find anything elsewhere and have never had this happen before.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. What did you try?

Comment: Python 3.8 is very fresh and some modules may not exist yet for this version. SO better go back to 3.7 and wait few months before it will better tested and some modules will be created for this version.

Comment: Found the same thing. Pygame installs and runs fine with Python37, but not with python38. Same problem posted here too: https://superuser.com/questions/1493749/ive-been-trying-to-install-pygame-but-i-keep-getting-this-error?r=SearchResults&newreg=f2062e38a9b048c4bb4b99f4d28746b5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow. We are glad to have you here. Sadly, I don't think pygame is very reliable with 3.8 at the moment. I would recommend downgrading back to 3.7 and installing with pip there.

Good luck!

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

[Unable to install pygame on Python 3.8 via pip (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-ia-pip-windows-10) 
Use the answer at the bottom for installing it. It'll be a little complex but follow the steps carefully. If you skip one part, you might get an error. It'll be in pygame 2.0.0 so you probably need to update your code.