# Unable to install pygame on Python via pip (Windows 10)

Tags: python, pip, pygame, python-3.8

Currently unable to install **[Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)** via [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/):

```
pip install pygame
```

Getting this message:

[image]

Concerned by it being termed an EOF error, is this an error in the module itself?

Comment: Same question is already asked for Windows 10 and python 3.8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469733/pip-install-eoferror

Comment: It looks like Python 3.8 wheels for Windows are now available on PyPI

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's `dev` versions available as of now. Get them via

```
pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

Comment: `pip install pygame==` list what versions are available

Comment: I had trouble using this with python3.8 Idle... if you want to install it in the right directory use: pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6 ... or pygame will be installed in python 2.7 directory (at least on MacOS)

Answer (score 6):

Pygame is not compatible with Python 3.8 at the moment. I would recommend you to downgrade back to 3.7 and installing with pip there.

Answer (score 0):

pip is doesn't have pygame up. 
But there is a alternative that worked for me. https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows 
Read and follow the steps correctly and it should install. 
you also need to update your code to pygame 2.0.0 code because it's only for 3.8
BTW you have to follow the SDL2 instructions since pygame 2.0.0 uses that.

Comment: You don't need to compile the master branch from the the repository, there's a branch `1.9.6-python3.8` which, when compiled and installed, gives you `pygame==1.9.6`.

Answer (score 0):

the above commands worked for me today 3-15-20 with Python-3-8-0 on Linux Mint 19
to get IDLE to recognize pygame.

sudo pip3 install pygame==2.0.0.dev6

I also had to update pip first with

sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 0):

Pygame requires visual studio C++ build tools to install. Ensure you have these downloaded from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019).

Answer (score -1):

Open power shell window and make sure your internet is on 
Then type the following command 
pip install pygame 
It will automatically download it for you and also install it 
Again make sure your internet is on 
I have python 3.8.2 and it worked on my pc

Comment: That's the command OP is using, already -- and there is also a solution. So what is the value added here?