# Why am I getting an error when installing pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame in Pycharm and get the Error "Command errored out with exit status 1."  Prior to this Error, I was getting an error that I was not running the latest version of pip which I've updated.  Also, I'm using pycharm's latest version 3.8.

Below is a link to the error msg. since I cannot post it in this thread since I'm new to this site.  Appreciate and feedback and help with this!  Thanks in advance.

Edit: Below is the Command Error msg.

Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\jkalber\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\jkalber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\jkalber\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\jkalber\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\jkalber\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\
Complete output (17 lines):


WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\jkalber\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\jkalber\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\jkalber\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\jkalber\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQI3H.png)

Comment: _I cannot post it in this thread since I'm new to this site_ What?  Clearly you _are_ able to post, because you made this post.

Comment: Add complete log information for better understanding

Comment: John: That's correct.  It would not let me post the image in the thread, hence the reason for the link.

Comment: It's nearly always better to post errors as text, not images.

Comment: Thanks for advising that.  I've re-edited with command error msg.

Comment: Python 3.8 is very new version and it may not have PyGame module created specially for 3.8 so better use 3.7 and wait few months.

Comment: You might be able to use a version from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install pygame on Python 3.8 via pip (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10)