# Cant install pygame

Tags: python, download, pygame, eof

So I've got a bit of an issue with python and/or pip...

Python, when asked to download pygame in CMD with `py -m pip install -U pygame --user`, gives me this error:

```
    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zalja6w\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zalja6w\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zalja6w\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\gary\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zalja6w\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

It seems to download the files just fine but does NOT like to continue after that. I'm running python 3.8. And yes, Python is installed in the PATH variable.

I feel like this could be a really stupid issue and I've just overlooked something but I cant seem to find anything that helps.

-----edit-----

I've worked out a bit of a solution - just download and use python 3.7 instead of 3.8 and that seems to work better.

Comment: try "python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user" as mentioned in offecial doc.

Comment: my python doesnt work when I use python3 as the command so when specifying python, since I only have one version, i just say py

Comment: it just gives me `'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: try pip install -U pygame --user

Comment: nope, same error

Comment: try the same code in power shell

Comment: that didnt work, but what i did do was download python 3.7 and that seems to have worked

Comment: For future reference, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using an IDE with the ability to automatically install imports (PyCharm for example) you can just set your IDE's current interpreter to python 3.7.4 and use it to install pygame instead of using pip. The problem has something to do with the pygame install not working with python 3.8 so either revert your interpreter, role back to python 3.7 or wait for pygame to get updated