# this error always comes up whenever i try to install pygame lab

Tags: python-3.x

Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-hovkmk98'
cwd: C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame
Complete output (17 lines):

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\chaurasiya\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: What'your command u run

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install pygame on Python 3.8 via pip (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10)

Comment: Try with python 3.7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517438/cant-install-pygame

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cant install pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517438/cant-install-pygame)

Comment: pip install pygame this i run, i'm using python 3.9