# Cannot install pygame package

Tags: python, pygame

I'm not able to install pygame package in python(64 bit). 
I tried installing it through pycharm (64 bit) by going to

```
files>settings>program name>program interpreter
```

then, when installing pygame, I'm facing this problem:

```
Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pygame\
```

The second thing I did was try it through the terminal there I got the same error. 
The previous version of my python and pycharm were of 32 bit then I changed to 64 bit. 
I'm now really stuck since I'm not able to even install other packages like kivy etc...

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: no im using python 3.8

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Unable to install pygame on Python 3.8 via pip (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10)

Pygame doesn't support python 3.8 but there's a way to install, please check the link.

Answer (score 1):

Pygame is not yet supported with 3.8 as it is unstable at the moment. In the meantime, I recommend downgrading to 3.7 and installing pygame with:

```
pip install pygame
```

In a few months 3.8 will have some modules implemented. Sorry for the inconvenience, hope this fixes your issue.