# Error when trying to install pygame on Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I tried installing pygame using

```
pip install pygame
```

I tried installing it using Python 3.8 but it outputs the error below.
I also tried installing using Python 3.7 but still no luck.

The error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe'
-c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_ptqagog\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Asus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_ptqagog\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ptqagog\pygame\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ptqagog\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ptqagog\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ptqagog\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ptqagog\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_ptqagog\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ---------------------------------------- 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: [Pygame Installation](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to install pygame on Python 3.8 via pip (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10)

Comment: @pavel OP stated in his question that it doesn't work with python 3.7 also.

Comment: @RMPR, somehow I missed that bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to install from the [Wheel](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/56/b63ab3724acff69f4080e54c4bc5f55d1fbdeeb19b92b70acf45e88a5908/pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl) file.

After verifying that you're using python 3.7

```sh
python --version # Python 3.7.X
pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thanks, after switching version to 3.7.4, it worked!

Answer (score 9):

Use this (I was facing the same issue and it helped me out):

```
pip install pygame --pre
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of OS system are you using? I have no problem to install on python 3.7

```
(base) $ python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
Collecting pygame
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/32/37/453bbb62f90feff2a2b75fc739b674319f5f6a8789d5d21c6d2d7d42face/pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_11_intel.whl (4.9MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.9MB 2.7MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-1.9.6
(base) $ python -m pygame.examples.aliens
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

If the problem persists, you should use `conda` or another environment manager to create new environment and then install the library.

Comment: I use Windows 10 Home SIngle Language

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Ventura :

Check for your python, pip version and list of installed packages :

In Terminal :

## Get version of python that is default

```
python -V
```

## Get the version of pip that is default

```
pip -V
```

## list installed packages

```
pip list
```

OUTPUT Sample for [ pip list]

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.1.2
setuptools 60.2.0
wheel      0.37.1
```

## Now install pygame

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Result :

> Collecting pygame    Downloading
> pygame-2.4.0-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (13.0 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 13.0/13.0 MB 5.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
>
> Installing collected packages: pygame Successfully installed
> pygame-2.4.0

Answer (score -2):

I'm not getting an error when I do this. Have you tried:

```
pip install pygame
```

Have you attempted installing with command-prompt or terminal? When I run what you are doing, I don't seem to get a problem.

Additionally, pygame is not compatible with 3.8 yet as it is unstable. Maybe wait a few months until modules are ready to be used with 3.8. Hope this helps, good day.

Comment: I did try installing by using that command on both version but no luck. Python 3.8 is not compatible, but my Python 3.7 also didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, but it's not helpful, since the first thing the original poster says is...I tried installing pygame using 'pip install pygame'