# Why is my pygame window not showing anything?

Tags: python, pygame

(python 3.8 and pygame 1.9.6)

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False

#main loop
while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 128, 255), pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))

pygame.display.flip()
```

Is there something like import os required?

Comment: Probably pygame is not installed correctly. pygame doesn't work on python 3.8. You've to downgrade to python 3.7.

Comment: but the aliens example works

Comment: Then there is no reason why the code from the answer should not work

Comment: yeah i know but it still not workin'

Comment: i doubt this:  is this version correct:   pygame-1.9.6-cp38-cp38-win32.whl

Comment: What does it mean *"aliens example works"*? Did you start it the same way?

Comment: yeah...Ctr+O in IDLE and then F5

Comment: you have wrong indentations - `rect()` and `flip()` should be inside `while`. And try it without IDLE. Check also if you don't run old code without changes. But I would also run Python 3.7 because 3.8 is very new version and it may have unknow bugs.

Comment: Apart from the indentation errors pointed out by @furas, pygame is not supported in python 3.8. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10)

Comment: @Valentino yeah i see....pygame 2.0 is reqd. or python 3.7....btw thank u everyone:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

1. You need to update the display **in** the main loop rather than **after** the main loop (`pygame.display.flip()`).
2. You need to draw the rectangle in the application loop rather than in the event loop:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False

#main loop
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 128, 255), pygame.Rect(30, 30, 60, 60))

#-->|
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: @GautamMehta This code works fine, I've tested it right now.

Comment: Very late but apart from the version....this was the issue..thanks