# Why won't my game display fill the background with white

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So far I am trying to create a display that will fill  with a white background. When i run my code the gameDisplay is black.

I have created the variable white and assigned it to the tuple (255,255,255) to get the correct colour. I have then asked my gameDisplay to fill with that variable.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode([display_width,display_height])
pygame.display.set_caption('A bit Racey')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.jpg')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)



crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

The expected result is a white display with a racecar image at the bottom centre. What I get is a  black display with no racecar image.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no obvious issue in this code. The code works fine. Is pygame even installed  on your system? Read [Unable to install pygame on Python 3.8 via pip (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489348/unable-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-8-via-pip-windows-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gameDisplay will be black because you have to flip(i dont know how to explain).
So you need to add pygame.display.flip()
Here is the code:

```
gameDisplay.fill(white)
car(x,y)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```