# pygame is installed through pip and can be imported in IDLE but isnt importing in pycharm,

Tags: pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrE8H.png)

somebody please help I have tried ctrl+alt+S and interpreter in pycharm but it wont work although the import pygame works on IDLE

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1) You have a virtual environment set in PyCharm as a project interpreter (see `venv` directory in the project root) instead of the system Python you probably have installed `pygame` on. Go to **Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter** and select the correct interpreter

2) There is a known issue with `pygame` installation on Python 3.8 on Windows, see [Unable to install pygame on Python 3.8 via pip (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58489348/2787185)