# How to compile pygame with extended image support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, pygame, python-3.9

I am following the instructions at https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows, and I've compiled pygame successfully! However, I still cannot get extended image support to work. [Pygame's documentation](http://The%20image%20module%20is%20a%20required%20dependency%20of%20pygame,%20but%20it%20only%20optionally%20supports%20any%20extended%20file%20formats.%20By%20default%20it%20can%20only%20load%20uncompressed%20BMP%20images.%20When%20built%20with%20full%20image%20support,%20the%20pygame.image.load()%20function%20can%20support%20the%20following%20formats.) says:

> The image module is a required dependency of pygame, but it only optionally supports any extended file formats. By default it can only load uncompressed BMP images.

How do I specify the option? I need pygame (with png support) for school, but also want the latest python version (3.9).

Comment: Why do you think you need to compile pygame, does `python -m pip install pygame` not work for you? Referring to the `pygame.image.load` [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load), what does `pygame.image.get_extended()` return on your system?

Comment: Using `pip` to install `pygame` returns an EOF error like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58469733/pip-install-eoferror. `pygame.image.get_extended()` returns `0`. @importrandom

Comment: You could try installing the latest development version of pygame 2 using `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev12`. This might be easier than recompiling the library.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work @importrandom

Comment: One final thing to try rather than recompiling is the precompiled wheels from Christoph Gohlke, there is are [pygame](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) wheel linked against 32 & 64-bit python 3.9

Comment: @importrandom thank you! that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there is pre-compiled wheel at [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)! Just `pip install` it and it works! Thanks to @importrandom for the help!